# Fatal error: Unsupported operand types on line 20

Tags: php, pyrocms

line 20: $this->data['available_credits'] = $total_credits - $used_credits;

```
    function index()   {
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $this->data['credits'] = $this->credit_m->get_credit_details($user_id);
    $total_credits = $this->data['total_credits'] = $this->credit_m->get_total_credits($user_id);
    $used_credits = $this->data['used_credits'] = $this->credit_m->get_used_credits($user_id);
    $this->data['available_credits'] = $total_credits - $used_credits;
    $this->template->build('credits_view',$this->data);
}
```

Comment: Could you add a bit more context to your question? Are $total_credits and $used_credits numbers?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your `$total_credits` variables `$used_credits` don't contain numbers -- they probable contain some objects, which cannot be substracted.

Check what your `get_total_credits()` and `get_used_credits()` methods return ; make sure they return values that can be used with the substraction operator.